# # error FS0003: "This value is not a function and cannot be applied" on a simple function

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have this function in a F# script that keeps throwing the "this value is not a function and cannot be applied error":

```
let square x = x * x
```

Why is this happening?
It is the only line in the script

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/ZpWjGW). How are you compiling and running it?

Comment: I am running it in visual studio with the f# interactive.  I create a script in visual studio, then I select the function and run it in interactive

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to close visual studio and all of its services and restart.  It must be a bug within visual studio as once I did that the line compiled and ran.